# In Kafka, how to replay kafka consumers between two offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Given two offsets - a start and end offset, or start/end datetime timestamp (equally fine), I want a Kafka consumer to replay all messages within that window.

I have figured out how to reset offset using kakfa-consumer-groups.sh tool to reset the offset based on datetime or offset, but how do I tell the consumer to **stop** after say replaying for 10,000 messages or 10 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no configuration or API that lets you stop a KafkaConsumer after a certain amount of processed offsets or time.

You would need to do this programatically by checking the offsets of the ConsumerRecord or having a timer that will stop the Consumer after a certain time.

Instead of using kafka-consumer-groups tool you could also make use of the `seek` API of the KafkaConsumer to start at a particular offsets for a partition.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the answer. Can I invoke the same Java API inside Kafka Connector (sink connector)? I know I asked the question for a generic consumer, but I was initially only of thinking to use kafka-consumer-groups tool.

Comment: I am not so sure if this is possible with built-in functionality of a KafkaConnector. However, you can always write your own Connector with your own logic....